# What does 'politics of terminal exclusion' mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 'politics of terminal exclusion' mean?

> Exploitation is now matched by a **politics of terminal exclusion**.

Sentence from a post:
https://www.facebook.com/henry.giroux.3/posts/10162361597175157

Comment: More context would help. Can you add the surrounding text, at least a complete paragraph?

Comment: terminal means that ends something definitively. I think that guy is French, somehow. politics that exclude this or that group terminally. I would have said definitive.